# table cell not auto resizing according to uiimageview height

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, xcode-storyboard

UIImageView height width is set to fillparent. and using follwing code to auto resize table cell.

```
  DiscountTableView.Source = new DiscountsTVS(discounts);
  DiscountTableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 164;
  DiscountTableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
```

but i am getting following output

[image: screen shot from iphone simulator]
not sure what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can check working example here i hope this is useful for you.[Dynamic hieght of tableviewcell](https://github.com/paleksandrs/DynamicTableWithImages)

Answer (score 0):

If you used UITableView.AutomaticDimension ,you need to add constraints in the xib or in the code